# What's a Canadian equivalent of Super Safemove for U-Haul trucks in Canada?

Tags: canada, insurance, rental

I'll be renting a uhaul truck for one way move from Ottawa to Toronto in couple of weeks and I'm wondering whether there's a Canadian equivalent of Super Safemove damage coverage insurance? Only safemove is available in Canada which does not cover third party damage (damage done to others and their property). I've rented the same truck before with Safemove coverage without knowing this and now I realize that I really should get one this time. I've tried to find suitable insurance company that would help me with it but couldn't find any.

Comment: Hi Joseph, welcome to Travel.SE. Unfortunately, this question [does not fall under the scope of this Q&A site as defined in our FAQ](http://travel.stackexchange.com/faq). I'm sorry I have to close this. Do stick around and ask any travel-related questions you have though!